# Measurement error and the OLS assumptions

Tags: regression, least-squares, measurement-error

Can somebody offer an intuitive understanding of the difference in effect between measurement error of the independent variable and measurement error of the dependent variable in a linear regression model?

Comment: Here's [why measurement error in the *dependent* variable doesn't affect your coefficients much](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/129991), and here's [why you should worry about measurement error in the *independent* variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/225030).